# loop is stopping when it found 1st output

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

Problem:

Write a program to Display numbers from a list using loop

Write a program to display only those numbers from a list that satisfy the following conditions

The number must be divisible by five
If the number is greater than 150, then skip it and move to the next number
If the number is greater than 500, then stop the loop
Sample input : numbers = 12, 75, 150, 180, 145, 525, 50

Sample output : [75, 150, 145]

Sample input : numbers = 14, 85, 625, 75

Sample output : [85]

code:

```
def func(inputs):
      inputs = [int(i) for i in inputs]
      output = []
      for i in inputs:
          if i > 150:
              if i > 500:
                break
                continue
          if i % 5 == 0:
              output.append(i)
              return output
    inputs = input().split(', ')
    print(func(inputs))
```

Input: 14, 85, 65, 625, 75
Output: [85]

why loop is stopping when it found the first output.

Comment: Your code returns in the loop, so the first time you see a valid value, you're done.

Comment: You've got a `break` and a `continue` right next to each other; one of them will never execute? Also, from the code, it seems like you're looking for a number greater than 150, then immediately testing to see if it's greater than 500, and if so, stopping the entire loop. Only if the number is not greater than 150, you test if the number is divisible by 5, and if so, append it to the outputs.

Comment: inputs = [12, 150, 180, 145, 525, 50]
output = []
for i in inputs:
    if i > 150:
        if i > 500:
          break
        continue
    if i % 5 == 0:
        output.append(i)
        
print(output)

Comment: this code is working fine... but the above one is not??!!

Comment: @wkl  can you please explain.

Comment: @lancylot2004  please sir

Comment: Your `return output` is in the `if i % 5 == 0` block. The moment you find an `i` that is divisible by 5, you add it to `output` and then return it. So you will only ever find one item, at most.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple issues in your code that wouldn’t satisfy the requirements you’ve listed.

1. You never skip the number if it’s greater than 150. You only check if the number is greater than 150, then greater than 500, and then `break` if so.
2. Your loop stops after it finds the first number divisible by 5, because you do:

   ```
   if i % 5 == 0:
       output.append(i)
       return output
   ```

   Do you see the problem? You append to `output` and then immediately do `return output`, so you’d only ever get one value.

You need to reorder your conditionals and return `output` only after you’re done with the loop.

```
def func(inputs):
  inputs = [int(i) for i in inputs]
  output = []
  for i in inputs:
      if i > 500:
          break
      if i > 150:
          continue
      if i % 5 == 0:
          output.append(i)
  return output
```